# Opening a new form, and closing the form that called it

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button on the first form, that when clicked opens a second form and closes the first.
However, no mater what I do 'both' forms close.

This is the button on the first form:

```
private void btnReports_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form f2 = new frmForm2();
        f2.Show();            
    }
```

And this is the code in the Load event of the second form

```
private void frmReports_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.OpenForms["frmForm1"].Close();
    }
```

I also tried

```
private void btnReports_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form f2 = new frmForm2();
        f2.Show();   
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: did you try to use ShowDialog(YourMainForm) instead?

Comment: u can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698080/spawn-a-new-thread-to-open-a-new-window-and-close-it-from-a-different-thread

Answer (score 3):

You probably have this as startup:

```
Application.Run(new frmForm1());
```

If frmForm1 is closed then the application stops. You should hide the form using `frmForm1.hide();`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following [Application.Run(ApplicationContext)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157901.aspx) method. There is an example on how to set up your application so that it will only exit when the last form is closed, not when the main form is closed.