# LoadingScreen drawing issue without Application.DoEvents Why?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, progress-bar, long-running-processes

I have a mainform with a simple button to test my loading screen.

[image]

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void loadingscreenTest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 100;
        LoadingScreen f2 = new LoadingScreen(0, count, 1);
        f2.Show();
        //Application.DoEvents();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            f2.performstep();
        }
    }
}
```

LoadingScreen is a simple form with a ProgressBar on it.

[image]

It's code is the following:

```
public partial class LoadingScreen : Form
{
    public LoadingScreen(int current, int max, int step)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.progressBar1.Maximum = max;
        this.progressBar1.Step = step;
        this.progressBar1.Value = current;
    }

    public void performstep()
    {
        this.progressBar1.PerformStep();
    }
}
```

I know that you are not supposed to run long running processes in the UI thread, however in this scenario i can't see why is it that when i press the button, the LoadingScreen form has trouble drawing its content without the Application.DoEvents call. Can you please help me understand this phenomenon?

The Issue persists for like 1 to 2 seconds but what is buggin me is that I don't understand why.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and .Net 4.0

[image]

Comment: *"why is it that when i press the button, the LoadingScreen form has trouble drawing its content without the Application.DoEvents call"*, because when you call `f2.Show()` in UI thread, you are not yet release it for draw. So no draw, until you explicitly call [`PerformStep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.performstep(v=vs.110).aspx), which internally calls invalidate and repaint the form for the first time. Notice, you are still not allow any user interaction with this form. Try to exchange `Sleep` and `PerformStep` to see some difference..

Comment: When you are blocking UI thread be ready for ugly solutions (like calling `DoEvents` one).

Comment: You could throw the progress into another thread and have it callback to the main form for update. This would keep your UI thread available for the call.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698080/spawn-a-new-thread-to-open-a-new-window-and-close-it-from-a-different-thread

Comment: Sinatr Your answer is quite helpful, could you please direct me to a page where this behaviour of winforms in documented? It's as you've said, however the LoadingScreen window only recieves the WM_PRINTCLIENT message when the 2nd PerformStep is being called.